vsftpd is unable to go into root directory when chroot_local_user=YES
I have installed vsfptd and created a user using this
sudo useradd sftp -d /var/www/magento2
Then I did this config for vsftpd
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
local_root=/var/www/magento2
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
force_dot_files=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
log_ftp_protocol=YES
pasv_enable=NO
# SSL
ssl_enable=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH

When I have this config and I am connecting using Filezilla it's taking me to / directory instead of /var/www/magento2 but when I am commenting out this line chroot_local_user=YES I can go to any folder.
How can I fix this and my user should have only access to the /var/www/magento2 folder and the user shouldn't be able to go other folders.
